# vb6 reference for WMI class

Tags: vb6, wmi

I am trying to use `WMI` in my `VB6` program but I get general error at the first `GetObject` call.

```
Dim ProcessorSet As Object
Dim CPU As Object
Dim GetOsBitness As String

Set ProcessorSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:"). _
    ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
For Each CPU In ProcessorSet
    GetOsBitness = CStr(CPU.AddressWidth)
Next
```

What reference(s) do I need for the WMI class?

Is that the problem?

`WMI` service is running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is likely your problem.

Try adding a reference to the "WMI Scripting Library" (**wbemdisp.tlb**). Depending on your OS, if it's not immediately in the references you can add to your project (name might contain WBEM or something similar) you might need to locate it somewhere in the windows\system32\wbem folder, and reference that.

Comment: Thanks.  I have wbemdisp.tlb and wbemcntl.dll referenced but still not working.

Comment: Does the same WMI from a VBS script correctly? It might be OS related, which OS are you running this on?

Comment: Yes, I did make a VBS script and ran it from command window.
I am running Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: Try referencing the wbemdisp.tlb from the Syswow64\wbem folder if you have not done so already.

Comment: Ok, tried that. No change. In the mean time I got something working with API calls. But then ran into problem of detecting a 64 bit process from a 32 bit application. Can't do it according to several threads here.  That is what I am really trying to do, get path of a running executable(not mine), which tells me something about what version of the program someone is running. There are 32bit and 64bit versions of the program.